# 700k capital gain on primary residence sale. How will I be taxed?

Tags: united-states, capital-gain, primary-residence

I am married and should qualify for the joint 500k exemption for primary residences. Assuming a 100k/year income, my question is if the IRS will consider our income to be 300k or 800k for the year? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have a $700K cap gain. $500K exclusion. So you're left with a $200K long term cap gain.

Comment: I think the question as to whether that gain would be included in Income.

Comment: Cap gains are taxed differently, they are not ordinary income. Not as simple as saying taxed on $300 vs $800.

Comment: Buy they are included in AGI, correct?

Comment: Yes, it works its way to that line.

Comment: @DStanley - I was avoiding the tangent of earned income vs other income. Each is taxed differently, and has other impact to one's full return. The question itself was almost a yes/no question, and the answer is that if OP lived there for 2 of the last 5 years, he got the $500K exclusion correct, and will only show the $200K gain. If you feel there's something else I should clarify in my answer, I'm happy to do so. I went for brevity, and have a basic one line answer.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer- not saying you're wrong - I was focusing on the question " if the IRS will consider our income to be 300k or 800k for the year?".  I think the answer is 300k since the long term gain is part of AGI. I'm not sure what the reason for the question is, though, to be sure.

Comment: I  did not take your comment that way. Just looking for some advice on how you felt I could improve the answer given the limited nature of the question

Answer (score 1):

<del>The gain is sale price - cost basis.</del>

Up to 500k of the gain is excludable.  [IRS Topic 701 - Sale of your Home.](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc701.html)  Links from there explain cost basis and rules for the exclusion and explanation of gains and losses.

The non-excludable part will be taxed according to the duration of the investment.  It will be taxed as a capital gain.